# Removing the file with same name, extension doesn't matter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, file-extension

I have some files in `"~Content/Documents"` folder which holds every uploaded file. In my case the user can only upload one file.

I have done the uploading part where the user can upload his file.

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var fullpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents");
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fullpath,"document"+Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
}
```

My problem is:
User can upload either `".doc", ".docx", ".xls", ".xlsx", or ".pdf"` format files.
Now when the user upload the file of `".doc"` format it is uploaded to the folder. Later the same user can upload the file of `".pdf"` format which is also uploaded to the folder. That means the user can upload two files.

Now what I want to do is:
When a specific user uploads his document: 
->search whether the document uploaded by the user is in that folder or not. i.e. the specific filename with different extension exists or not. 
->if the filename already exists with different extension then remove that file and upload the new file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, Just another way; If your filename is `"document"`

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullpath,"document.*");
foreach (string f in files)
{
   System.IO.File.Delete(f);
}
```

**So your code would be;**

```
if (file.ContentLength > 0)
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    var fullpath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Documents");

    //deleting code starts here
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fullpath,"document.*");
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
       System.IO.File.Delete(f);
    }
    //deleting code ends here
    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fullpath,"document"+Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick

```
  var files = new DirectoryInfo(fullpath).GetFiles();
  var filesNoExtensions = files.Select(a => a.Name.Split('.')[0]).ToList();
    //for below: or 'document' if that's what you rename it to be on disk
  var fileNameNoExtension = fileName.Split('.')[0]; 
  if (filesNoExtensions.Contains(fileNameNoExtension))
  {
    var deleteMe = files.First(f => f.Name.Split('.')[0] == fileNameNoExtension);
    deleteMe.Delete();
  }
  file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(fullpath,"document"+Path.GetExtension(fileName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the filename of the new file without extension, then loop through all the filenames in the folder where it will be uploaded to and check if the name already exists. If so, delete the old an upload, else upload.

```
var info = new FileInfo("C:\\MyDoc.docx");
var filename = info.Name.Replace(info.Extension, "");
var files = Directory.GetFiles("YOUR_DIRECTORY").Select(f => new FileInfo(f).Name);

if (files.Any(file => file.Contains(filename)))
{
    //Delete old file
}
//Upload new file
```