# Editing image file name in SQL and deleting actual image if there is modification

Tags: c#, sql, io, picturebox

I have function in my app to edit the user details in that there is feature which allows us to edit the image in the picturebox.

What I am trying to achieve is if user choose to edit the image to another the app should delete the current image and use the new image and save to db. If users edit other details without touching picturebox then no changes should be made.

I have written below code but but it's not working can correct me or suggest better solution for what I am trying to achieve.

```
       string picPath
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        openFileDialog.Filter = "Image files|*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.bmp;*.gif";
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            string FileName = openFileDialog.FileName;
            profilePicPictureBox.ImageLocation = FileName;
        }

        if (File.Exists(@"D:\Local Pictures\Users\" + fnameTextBox.Text + "_" + lnameTextBox.Text + "_" + userIdTextBox.Text + ".jpg"))
        {
            File.Delete(@"D:\Local Pictures\Users\" + fnameTextBox.Text + "_" + lnameTextBox.Text + "_" + userIdTextBox.Text + ".jpg");
            picPath = (@"D:\Local Pictures\Users\" + fnameTextBox.Text + "_" + lnameTextBox.Text + "_" + userIdTextBox.Text + ".jpg");
            profilePicPictureBox.Image.Save(picPath);
        }
```

when i try to execute the above i am getting a exception on relative path

Comment: what is your exception?

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha i should mentioned earlier the file.exist if statement and opendialog codes are in separate classes i have copied and pasted here so above code not full it's partial and exeception i getting that image file not found on debug folder.

Comment: "If users edit other details without touching picturebox then no changes should be made. " so how do u going to check does user touch picturebox? if user touch picturebox does filedialogbox popup?

Comment: Try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13759648/removing-the-file-with-same-name-extension-doesnt-matter It may help you.

Comment: @madhawapriyashantha i was thinking like the filename old picture will exist in db so after user editing the details click a button it will check whether both are same if answer yes then no change but if there different then go with edit process

Comment: ok.if your error filenot found then check manually really it exist .
console.writeline("D:\Local Pictures\Users\" + fnameTextBox.Text + "_" + lnameTextBox.Text + "_" + userIdTextBox.Text + ".jpg");